# Bitcoin in wallet transactions but not on the blockchain (old wallet)

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet

I've been checking old wallets and found an unconfirmed transaction that's on the wallet but not on the blockchain

```
transaction id (missing from blockchain)
ab5eb776a36b5552570088ba7bf3563780c91f0044c2a170481f75a5004dfe2a

receive address (showing 0 BTC)
1LwBvLheVfjP3RUTipZtPRRPa13GSH2sAY
```

My wallet showing a transaction

[image]

How do I access these BTC and get them onto the blockchain? I could be wrong but I believe that it's such an old unconfirmed transaction that it doesn't even show on the blockchain.

So far I have tried forcing the transaction to go through again with a hex code of the transaction on https://blockchain.info/pushtx, but it didn't work

Please help! It's a long shot but the amount of BTC is huge, so I want to try every approach at accessing the BTC before giving up.

Comment: When i tried "sendrawtransaction <massive hex code>" it tells me Ibad-txns-inputs-missingorspent (code -25). Is there any way to get a miner to fix this or will the BTC just never be spendable maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you won't be able to access these funds.

> How do I access these BTC and get them onto the blockchain? I could be wrong but I believe that it's such an old unconfirmed transaction that it doesn't even show on the blockchain.

The transaction is not, and has never been, confirmed on chain. From the perspective of the network, it doesn't exist.

> So far I have tried forcing the transaction to go through again with a hex code of the transaction on https://blockchain.info/pushtx, but it didn't work

If that doesn't work, it likely means the transaction is spending funds that no longer exist (i.e., it was double spent). The error you get from `sendrawtransaction` does not mean anything, as your node is not fully synchronized yet.

Regardless, I'd suggest to let your node synchronize with the network. It's possible that it has received other transactions at that time, which did get confirmed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time :)

Answer (score -3):

@Adjam, this should definitely be investigated.  Perhaps a memory exercise would help you recall the associated circumstances.

Think back to 2014. You were running Bitcoin.  April.    A single Bitcoin was worth $505.  You're watching TV, eating Cheetos.  Somebody sends you $12.6 million dollars.

Then what happened?

p.s. hello Pieter!

p.p.s. Also, did anyone mention looking closer at the wallet?  Isn't it supposed to contain a full history? I don't know much about these things, TBH.

Answer (score -5):

Honestly you should be involving several federal agencies if you've misplaced your billion dollars.  FBI, IRS, SEC, Secret Service, Attorney General, 911....

Tip: for your next billion, maybe put your bitcoins in a bank, where it's federally insured.